# How to edit and save settings in a Form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, settings

I have a form that contains several text boxes, radio buttons, checkboxes etc. Right now I am saving their values respectively by declaring each one and saving to the programs settings:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.EmailFrom = txtbxEmailFrom.Text;
```

I would like to find a way to loop through all the objects and save their settings if possible so I don't have to declare each one individually.

Is there a way to do this? Or a better way to save the text of my textboxes, the checkstate of checkboxes & radiobuttons etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [property binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/wabtadw6(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#to-create-new-application-settings-using-visual-studio) to application settings.

This way you can simply save settings by calling `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` and you don't need to loop over controls, because the properties are bound to settings and their values automatically push into settings on change.

You can bind properties to settings using designer or using code.

**Using Designer**

select your control at design time, then in property grid, under `(ApplicationSettings)` click `...` for `(PropertyBinding)` and from the dialog, bind the properties you need to the settings.

**Using Code**

You can bind properties to settings, using code the same way you do it when data-binding using code:

```
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(
    new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Properties.Settings.Default, "Test", true,
        DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

**Save Settings**

To save settings, it's enough to call `Save()` on settings object some where like `Closing`  event of form:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

**Note**

As an alternative to different controls for settings, you can also use a `PropertyGrid` to show all the settings and edit them.

**More information:**

- [How To: Create a new setting at design time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-new-setting-at-design-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How To: Read Settings at Run Time With C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-read-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: Pretty nice solution!!

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to loop through all the controls and in each iteration check the type of the current control and save accordingly. However I'm not too sure what you can do about the RadioButtons/CheckBoxes.

```
foreach (var c in this.Controls)
{
    var _type = c.GetType();
    if (_type == typeof(TextBox))
    {
        // Cast it to a textbox and save it's text property
    }
    elseif (_type == typeof(ListBox)
    {
        // Cast it to a listbox and save it's items property
    }
    // So on...
 }
```