# Copy the state of controls and variables from one Form to another in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I have a windows form. If the user doesn't select a checkbox, a new form opens later when they press next, but if they do select it, the same form is used.
I want a clone of the current form to appear (with the same variable and control values) if they select the checkbox, so that they can change values later without deselecting the checkbox, and pressing next again, and typing in the other values manually.
`Form duplicate = this;` just references the same form and there is no such thing as `new(this)`.
I couldn't try `Form duplicate = new Form() = this` as my form takes constructors from an earlier form
Anyone knows how to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have many state variables that you need to clone ? Cloning the whole form hierarchy (controls and children and events all down the way) seems a big mess for me and i advise you not to do that. If you have 5 - 10 controls that you want to clone the state of, better stick with a method that does that for these specific controls.

Comment: What method clones controls with their values(I only want the `.text` values copied)

Comment: And Checked for `CheckBoxes` for example ?

Comment: you could add a second constructor to your form where you can pass the values you need.

Comment: How can I create an array of all the variables and of all the textboxes' `.text` values

Comment: @MarkPerera I fixed some typos in the answer and switched some `Key`s to `Value`s. You might want to fix that from your side too if you haven't.

Comment: @MarkPerera You can use Property Binding to Application Settings. This way you can bind properties of your control to settings at design-time and the at run-time the values of properties will be load from settings and if changed, you can save them in saved in settings for the next time. You may find these posts useful: [How to save all form settings without declaring each object?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34483981/3110834) and this one [Save options in VB.Net or C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32487895/3110834)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add these method inside your form:

```
public void RestoreState(Dictionary<string, object> controlStates, 
                         Dictionary<string, object> membersStates)
{
    InternalRestoreControls(controlStates);
    InternalRestoreMembers(membersStates);
}

private void InternalRestoreControls(Dictionary<string, object> states)
{
    foreach (var state in states)
    {
        Control c = this.Controls.Find(state.Key, true).FirstOrDefault();

        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            (c as TextBox).Text = state.Value == null ? null : state.Value.ToString();
        }
        else if (c is CheckBox)
        {
            (c as CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(state.Value);
        }
    }
}

private void InternalRestoreMembers(Dictionary<string, object> membersStates)
{
    // you might need to tweek this a little bit based on public/instance/static/private
    // but this is not the point of your question

    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static
                       | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

    var props = this.GetType().GetProperties(flags);
    var fields = this.GetType().GetFields(flags);

    foreach(var variable in membersStates)
    {
        var prop = props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == variable.Key);

        if(prop != null)
        {
            prop.SetValue(this, variable.Value);
            continue;
        }

        var field = fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == variable.Key);

        if(field != null)
        {
            field.SetValue(this, variable.Value);
            continue;
        }
    }
}

private Dictionary<string, object> GetControlsState()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { txtBox1.Name, txtBox1.Text },
        // continue to the rest
    };
}

private Dictionary<string, object> GetMembersState()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { nameof(variable1), variable1 },
        // continue to the rest
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
Form duplicate = new Form();
duplicate.RestoreState(this.GetControlsState(), this.GetMembersState());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:
Let's pretend you want to open the "clone" with a button.
In the to cloning form:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(string YourValue, int AnotherValue)     //This basically works like a constructor when the form is called
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ValueLabel1.Text = YourValue;
        ValueLabel2.Text = Convert.ToString(AnotherValue);
    }

    private void DuplicateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = 3;
        Form1 Window = new Form1(TextBox1.Text, a);
        Window.Show;
    }
```

I hope this works for you

Comment: There are like 15 textboxes, and I already have contructors for another purpose

Comment: It's a bit more complicated but you could code an object with the properties `TextBox1` `TextBox2` etc and give them the value. Afterwards you save it as xml and when you call he form again with show you load the xml file and assign the values each of your TextBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dictionary with control Name as Key and control Value as value and pass it as an optional parameter

```
public form1(string para1, int para2, Dictionary<string,object>yourDic=null)
{

}
```

Comment: Yes save your control names and values like text or bool's in the dictionary.When you load the form you can check if the dictionary is null.and if it's not null you could fill your controls with that values.