# Keep all form always on top - Apply one setting to multiple forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have multiple forms. One of them is called Settings and contains a checkbox with the following code:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        this.TopMost = true;
    }
    else if (!checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        this.TopMost = false;
    }
}
```

Now, this only works when I'm on the Settings form. As soon as I open another form e.g. the Program form (this closes the Settings form) it doesn't stay on top. Through the checkbox ApplicationSettings property I already made the checkbox stay on checked/unchecked if a user closes and reopens the Settings form. But this won't make the always on top feature work on the other forms.

How can I make other forms aswell stay on top of other programs after checking the checkbox in the Settings form and closing the checkbox form?

Comment: Check the setting as each form loads/opens/is created and act accordingly?

Comment: Create a settings.setting file for your project and save the checked value in a bool setting property. Then for each form, you can bind TopMost property to that setting. You can also put this logic inside a base form and other forms derive from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a bool property in Settings file of the project, save the checkbox checked property into the settings. Then for each form, you can bind `TopMost` property to that setting. You can also put binding logic inside a base form and other forms derive from it.

**Example**

1. Solution explorer → Your project → Properties node → double click on Settings.settings
2. Add a new property, Name = `TopMost` and Type = `bool` and set the value to `false` and set the Scope = `User` and save settings.
3. In the form which is responsible for editing the settings, in the `Load` event handler, read the `Checked` value of `CheckBox` from settings and in the `Click` event handler of the save button, save the `CheckBox.Checked` into the setting property:

   ```
    private void SettingForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        topMostCheckBox.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.TopMost;
    }
    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.TopMost = topMostCheckBox.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
   ```
4. In the other forms, or in a base form, setup the property bindings to the setting using designer or using code:

   ```
    private void BaseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("TopMost", Properties.Settings.Default, 
            "TopMost", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    }
   ```

Since it has been setup using data-binding, as soon as you save settings, `TopMost` will be applied to all new and open forms which derive from this base form.

**More information:**

- [How To: Create a new setting at design time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-new-setting-at-design-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How To: Read Settings at Run Time With C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-read-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Property binding (data binding) to application settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34483981/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

For new forms opened after the checkbox is selected, you must set `TopMost` from a global variable on initialization.

If you want to set `TopMost` on all currently open forms, you can loop through them, like so:

```
  foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
      frm.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: Not a good idea. It doesn't work for new forms that you open.

Comment: That's what I said. For new forms you must have a global variable. I see you have a good method for that above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in Settings Form it only be run for Setting Form.
To go for all forms
Declare a public static class

```
  public static class isTopMost
{
    public static bool TopMost;
}
```

Settings Forms

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
isTopMost.TopMost=checkBox1.Checked;
this.TopMost =  isTopMost.TopMost; // add this line all forms form_load events
        }
```